# How to Hold/Defer only one (only given) level?

Tags: list-manipulation, hold

Is it possible to Hold/Defer some of outer expressions, having evaluates inner ones?

For example, I want to prepare a table of expression values, like this

```
Table[Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm
```

Currently this displays left hand sides as

```
Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2
```

but can I have `x`-s evaluated/substituted?

**UPDATE**

Or just simpler example.

Suppose I write

```
x = 12
Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2
```

which gives

```
12
Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1.
```

but can I have

```
12
Sin[12]^2 + Cos[12]^2 == 1.
```

Comment: Are you working on V10?

Comment: No, I have V9. What advantages V10 has?

Comment: @SuzanCioc v10 has a set of functions exactly for this. Please check [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html).

Comment: Incredible. Why did they wait 9 versions?

Answer (score 1):

Your can use Replace* inside Hold or Deffer like this:

```
x = 12;
test = Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2
```

> Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1.

```
Block[{x}, test /. x -> y] /. y -> x
```

> Sin[12.]^2 + Cos[12.]^2 == 1.

Just idea, no doubt better approach can be found.

Comment: It seems to be even a bit more simple than that: `Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 /.x -> 12// Simplify `yields what you need.

Comment: I assume that x has a value, so 12->12.

Comment: In my code x has no value. I do not see your point.

Comment: Not my point. It is put in the formulation of the task: x=12;

Comment: Nice, but Alexei's solution in its present form doesn't work in a table, i.e. Table[Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 /. x -> 12 //     Simplify, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm

Comment: @Cris Degen I again do not see the point: try this: `Table[Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 /. x -> 12 //Simplify, {x0, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm `, since the right-hand part is always 1. But even less I see the point in making a table of 10 equal elements by that complex trick. I do not imagine that OP needs that, so s/he should formulate more clearly what s/he is after.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping `Hold` or `HoldForm` over all the elements effectively freezes the expression for easier manipulation.  (This method was used in R. Maeder's Programming in Mathematica, page 137.)

```
x = 12.;
Replace[Map[HoldForm, Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2], Infinity] ,
  HoldForm[x] -> HoldForm[12]] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2
```

> Sin[12]^2+Cos[12]^2==1.

And in a table:

```
Table[
  ReplaceAll[Map[HoldForm, Defer[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2], Infinity] ,
    HoldForm[x] -> HoldForm[Evaluate[x]]] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2,
  {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm
```

**Simpler method**

```
Table[With[{y = x}, Defer[Sin[y]^2 + Cos[y]^2] == Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2],
  {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate)/[`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate):

```
TableForm @ Activate @ Table[
    Inactivate @ Defer[Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2] == Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2,
    {x, 0, 1, 0.1}
] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{c}
>  \sin ^2(0.)+\cos ^2(0.)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.1)+\cos ^2(0.1)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.2)+\cos ^2(0.2)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.3)+\cos ^2(0.3)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.4)+\cos ^2(0.4)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.5)+\cos ^2(0.5)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.6)+\cos ^2(0.6)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.7)+\cos ^2(0.7)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.8)+\cos ^2(0.8)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(0.9)+\cos ^2(0.9)=1. \\
>  \sin ^2(1.)+\cos ^2(1.)=1. \\
> \end{array}$